# Creating my first container in Docker and need a little assistance

Tags: docker

I've just installed docker and I'm following the ‘[Getting started tutorial][1]’

[1]: http://localhost/tutorial/our-application/ which is packaged within the Docker install. At the beginning of the tutorial it says...

> In order to build the application, we need to use a Dockerfile. A
>   Dockerfile is simply a text-based script of instructions that is used
>   to create a container image. Create a file named Dockerfile with the
>   following contents.....

So far so good, but before issuing the 'Build' command it doesn't specify where I'm supposed to put/save the dockerfile??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your `Dockerfile` anywhere. You can specify the path to your `Dockerfile` when running `docker build` by using flag `--file`.

Answer (score 1):

A basic Docker folder structure would look something like this:

```
myapp/
  - src/
  - Dockerfile
  - docker-compose.yml (optional: If you want to use docker-compose)
```

And the folder structure if you are using multiple services using `docker-compose` would be:

```
myapp/
  - app1/
    - src/
    - Dockerfile
  - app2/
    - src/
    - Dockerfile
  - docker-compose.yml
```

But, in these case, you cannot access the files outside the folder containing Dockerfile. In those cases, as mentioned by @Nguyễn you can use a `--file` flag along with `docker build`.